# Is IServiceCollection.AddSingleton thread-safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, singleton

Consider the following extension function:

```cs
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AttachNativeLogger(this IServiceCollection services, ILogger logger)
    {
        // internal mechanism to forward native logging to ILogger interface:
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(services);
        var curLevel = Enum.GetValues(typeof(LogLevel)).Cast<LogLevel>().FirstOrDefault(logger.IsEnabled);
        var implementationInstance = new NativeLoggerForwarder(logger);
        implementationInstance.SetLogLevel(curLevel);
        // not thread safe ?
        services.AddSingleton(typeof(NativeLoggerForwarder), implementationInstance);

        return services;
    }
}
```

In the above code, should I enclose: `services.AddSingleton(typeof(NativeLoggerForwarder), implementationInstance)` inside a `lock(object)` ?

Since this is a static class, I fail to understand how I could possibly do it since I cannot define an external:

```
public class A {
    private static Object object = new Object();
    private static void foo() {
        lock(object) {
            // thread-safe
        }
    }
}
```

The documentation does not mention anything about thread-safety related issue at:

- [ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddSingleton Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton)

Comment: Do you expect multiple threads to be adding items to the service collection at the same time? I'm doubtful that any methods for manipulating the registered services are thread safe, and it seems unnecessary.

Comment: oh right, by construction this is thread-safe ...

Answer (score 2):

By looking at :

- https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/src/ServiceCollection.cs

I'd say it's not thread-safe, without going into questioning why you would setup a container from multiple threads. I didn't encounter any locks or concurrent collections used.

> In the above code, should I enclose: services.AddSingleton(typeof(NativeLoggerForwarder), implementationInstance) inside a lock(object) ?

Additionally you'd have to check if the service is registered already.

[image]

[image]

[image]